# Problem with java in r script on Google colab

Tags: java, r, google-colaboratory, rjava, bartmachine

Please excuse me if I ask the question in an incorrect format, it is my first time posting here:

I am trying to run a model build a model primarily using the bartMachine package on r.

I was able to run the script successfully when I had access to a server, so I know the script is fully functional. Unfortunately, I no longer have access to that server, and the script crashes my machine. I decided to try and run the script on google colab using the R runtime (as opposed to using the R magic cells option). When I run the model I get the following error:

```
"Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  "invalid class “jobjRef” object: invalid object for slot "jobj" in class 
  "jobjRef": got class "NULL", should be or extend class "externalptr"
```

I know that the problem is related to java and I have tried countless fixes, none of which were successful.

Any ideas?

- Sean