# Error when using predict on bartmachine object

Tags: r, bartmachine

I am writing the following script:

```
#options(java.parameters = "-Xmx50000m")
library(bartMachine)
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100, 5, 2), 
                   z=rnorm(100, 1, 0.5), 
                   y=as.factor(rep(c("a", "b"), 100)))

model <-  bartMachine(X= data[,c("x", "z")],
                           y= data$y, seed = 999,
                           serialize = T)

test <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000, 5, 2.5), 
                   z=rnorm(1000, 1, 0.7))

pred <- predict(model, test)
```

On my real world example, I get the following message when calling predict:

> Error in validObject(.Object) :
> invalid class “jobjRef” object: invalid object for slot "jobj" in class "jobjRef": got class "NULL", should be or extend class "externalptr"

Has anyone seen this error before? I haven't been able to find much online. Apologies for not being able to replicate the issue.

@Sean [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65417823/problem-with-java-in-r-script-on-google-colab) about a similar error message.

Comment: I am not getting this error. I am using `R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044) [1] bartMachine_1.3.3.1   missForest_1.5        randomForest_4.7-1.1  bartMachineJARs_1.2.1
 [5] rJava_1.0-6`. What is your R and bartMachine version?

Comment: `R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7`

Answer (score 0):

Increasing memory allocation resolved the issue:

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx500000m")
```